# Slice mesh with trimesh

Tags: python, mesh, trimesh

I work on a big .stl file which I want to cut into pieces using a bounding box.
For this purpose, I use `trimesh` python package to load the .stl.

Here is the piece of code used to generate the bounding box :

```
box = trimesh.creation.box(extents=[1.5, 1.5, 1.5])
    print(box.facets_origin)
    print(box.facets_normal)
```

So I get as a return :

```
print(box.facets_origin)
[[-0.75 -0.75  0.75]
 [ 0.75 -0.75 -0.75]
 [-0.75  0.75 -0.75]
 [-0.75 -0.75  0.75]
 [-0.75  0.75  0.75]
 [ 0.75  0.75 -0.75]]

print(box.facets_normal)
 [[-1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

This means that the box's center of gravity is at (0, 0, 0)

And then I plan to cut the big stl using `slice_plane function`.
However, I would like to change the location of the bounding box's center of mass, or facets' location.

How this could be done using trimesh ? Or another Python package ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Joachim

Answer (score 1):

Can you not translate the box using

```
mesh.apply_transform(trimesh.transformations.scale_and_translate())
```

https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/master/trimesh/transformations.py

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks for the quick answer !